# vb.net parameterized query error

Tags: vb.net

> the parameterized query '(@ItemId nvarcharr(4000),@batchNo
>   nvarchar(4000),@Rate nvarchar(4' expects the parameter '@ItemId',
>   which was not supplied

```
    Dim str As String
    Dim transtype As String
    Dim transid As String
    Dim quantityout As Integer
    Dim discount As Integer
    Dim remarks As String
    cnn.Open()

    For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        transtype = "PI"
        transid = 1
        quantityout = 0
        discount = 0
        remarks = "Nothing"

        str = "insert into purchase.detail (TransactionType, TransactionId, ItemId, BatchNo, Rate, ExpiryDate, Quantity, QuantityOut, Total, Discount, Remarks) values (@transtype, @transid, @ItemId, @BatchNo, @Rate, @ExpiryDate, @Quantity, @qout, @Total, @discount, @remarks)"

        Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand(str, cnn)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemId", DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("itemid").Value)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNo", DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("batchno").Value)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rate", DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("rate").Value)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpiryDate", DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("expirydate").Value)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("quantity").Value)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transtype", transtype)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transid", transid)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qout", quantityout)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("total").Value)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", discount)
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", remarks)
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd3.Dispose()
    Next
    cnn.Close()
```

[image]

Comment: You don't ask a question. What's the actual value of `DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells("itemid").Value`?

Comment: It takes values from a gridcontrol

Comment: Does the DataGridView have the edit row (the row at the bottom that lets you add to the grid)? If so, you are probably hitting that line and that line has empty cells. This would mean that your table would look fine upon examination. If that's the case,you can easily just -2 instead of -1 in your for loop `For x As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2` so you don't hit that row.